# Symmetries of a Square $U_{24}$ and $\mathbb Z_{8}$ proving or disproving an Isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

The question is as follows.

Consider the following three groups: $\mathbb Z_{8}$, $U_{24}$ and the group of symmetries of the square. For each pair, determine if the two groups are
isomorphic. If they are isomorphic, give and explicit isomorphism and
if they are not, explain why they are not.

Firstly i want to list the elements of the symmetries of a square. 
I, $R_{90}$,$R_{180}$,$R_{270}$,H,V,$D_{1}$,$D_{2}$

For clarity (R= Rotation, H= flip horizontal axis V= Vertical D= Diagonal) 
i have labeled each corner of my square as each entry of this matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4& 3\end{pmatrix}$$

$$R_{90}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$

$$R_{180}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& 3 & 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix},$$
$$R_{270}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& 3 & 4 \\ 4 &1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix},$$
$$H=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& 3 & 4 \\ 4&3 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$V=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& 3 & 4 \\ 2& 1 & 4 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$
$$D_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& 3 & 4 \\ 1& 4 & 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$
$$D_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& 3 & 4 \\ 3& 2 & 1 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$

Now im fairly lost about $\mathbb Z_{8}$ because i think there will be elements in here without inverse's. Preferably id like to understand what this means exactly? as well as how i should be making it look.

Next is $U_{24}$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline a & x & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9&11&13&15&17&19&21&23 \\ \hline 1 & 1\cdot x & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9&11&13&15&17&19&21&23 \\ \hline 3 & 3\cdot x & 3 & 9 & 15 & 21&3&9&15&21&3&9&15&21 \\ \hline 5 & 5\cdot x & 5 & 15 & 1 & 11&21&7&17&3&13&23&9&19 \\ \hline 7 & 7\cdot x \\  \hline 9 & 9\cdot x \\ \hline
\hline 11 & 11\cdot x  \\ \hline
\hline 13 & 13\cdot x  \\ \hline
\hline 15 & 15\cdot x \\ \hline
\hline 17 &17\cdot x  \\ \hline
\hline 19 & 19\cdot x  \\ \hline
\hline 21 & 21\cdot x \\ \hline
\hline 23 & 23\cdot x \\ \hline \end{array}$$

i got this far and decided this was way too much work and its not what im supposed to be doing, clearly there is no isomorphism between the symmetries of a square and $U_{24}$  is there some easier way to prove this?

Edit
So there are a couple things that are pointed out below as incorrect, firstly this is way too much work. secondly gcd(12,3) = 3 not 1 so 3, 9, 12, 15 should not be in the table leaving only 8 elements. 
As well as pointed out below $\mathbb Z_{8}$ is the integers on addition mod 8 not multiplication.

Comment: ${\bf Z}_8$ is just $\{{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}}$ with addition modulo $8$. $U_{24}$ is the elements of ${\bf Z}_{24}$ that are invertible under multiplication modulo $24$, and those are the ones relatively prime to $24$, so, not $3$ or $9$ or ....

Comment: ok, that cuts out 3 terms still way too many entries. any advice on how to do this in a different way?

Comment: No, it cuts out 4 terms, leaving 8, which is exactly what you want. For the rest, @anon shows you how to go without writing out any tables.

Comment: uh yes 15 is 5*3 ... lol thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way: show that an abelian group cannot be isomorphic to a nonabelian group.

Observe that $Z_8$ and $U(24)$ are abelian, and check that the [dihedral group](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group%3aD8) is nonabelian, which can be done in general by simply finding any two elements that do not commute.

Next, show that if a group is cyclic of even order, it has a *unique* element of order two.

Observe that $Z_8$ is cyclic of order $8$. Find *two* elements in $U(24)$ of order two, i.e. such that the equation $n^2\equiv1~(24)$ is satisfied but $n\ne1$. The solution $n=-1\equiv23$ is obvious, so you only need one more. So keep adding $24$ to $1$ until you hit a perfect square (it doesn't take long!).

Comment: 5 * 5 are congruent to 1 mod 24 so we have $23^{2}$ and $5^{2} $ congruent to 1 mod 24 and what i think your saying is that there wont be two things in $Z_{8}$ with the same property?

Comment: Right, in Z8 there is only one element of order 2, but in U(24) there are at least two elements, and if they were isomorphic they would have the same number of elements of order 2.

Comment: I don't know how you guys figure this stuff out, i've been staring at this textbook for 12hrs and i might as well be reading it upside down! haha

Comment: As a rule of thumb, proving things are isomorphic is a lot harder than proving they are not isomorphic, so it's a good idea to check a few ways of seeing that two groups are not isomorphic before we try and check that they are isomorphic. And the surest way to show two groups are not isomorphic is to show one has a property that the other doesn't. Common properties include being abelian, having a given order, having a certain number of elements of a given order, or number of certain types of subgroups (normal, Sylow), and so forth. Cyclic groups are particularly clean and relatively simple.