# Is $U_{24}$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Group: U(24)
Group Description: The set of integers less than 24 and relatively prime to 24 with multiplication modulo 24.

Can anyone clarify what the cyclic mean?
I was trying to google the definition, and I couldn't get it...

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1276464/11619) seems to answer yours also.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/319186/11619) also answers your question in a different context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question

> Is $U(24)$ cyclic?

means

> Is there an element $g \in U(24)$ such that all elements of $U(24)$ are powers of $g$?

The answer is:

> No. $U(24)$ has order $8$ but every element has order at most $2$ because $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 24$ for all $a \in U(24)$.